# Does Joomla have back-end theme editor functionality, just like WordPress?

Tags: templates

One of my friends asked me to change something on his Joomla website. He has back-end login info, but doesn't have FTP access.

So, does Joomla have back-end theme editor, just like WordPress which i can edit all theme files. I know a little bit about WordPress and not Joomla.

Comment: To edit the CSS, you can edit the theme here: `media\editors\tinymce\skins`. Else if you don't have FTP access, you can open TinyMCE in the Plugin Manager (backend) and make some changes to presets, but not styling.

Comment: @user18787 - I edited your question and wrote a proper tag. The [editor](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/tags/editor/info) tag is used for questions related to content editors (WYSIWYG) like TinyMCE, but your question seems to be about Joomla [templates](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/tags/templates/info).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it has as well. While you are in admin area, from the top menu, go to

<kbd>Extensions</kbd> > <kbd>Templates</kbd> > <kbd>Templates</kbd>

Then click on the template name you want to edit its files. Now you can select a file from left hand side and edit it.

It's obvious that the server should have proper file/folder permission and security configurations.